# competitive math

Tags: applications

I hope everyone knows about competitive programming. There are so many sites where you can solve programming tasks and increase your rating.
I am curious, does site about something like this for math exist? 
The service, where we can solve different math tasks and compete with each other. 
P.S. I know, it's pretty hard to implement autocheck system for math tasks' solutions unlike in competitive programming.

Comment: To the extent that it exists, you're looking at it. There are various puzzle sites (I recommend "Using Your Head Is Permitted"), but the idea of 'tasks' is alien to math, outside of homework for undergrad or pre-undergrad classes. There are plenty of sites like Project Euler (as GEdgar mentions) below for programming exercises or puzzles with some computer science, applied math, or occasionally theoretical math thrown in, but I'm not familiar with any equivalent of it for math.

Comment: I mean the site only for math and maybe useful only for school students and undergraduate. For example, what if I'm bad in math but I want to get some skills in solving tasks and understanding. Usually game like or competitive learning is the best way to learn something quickly. I wonder why I can't find something like this

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of problem would qualify as both straightforward enough to be a task but deep enough not to be trivial. I guess you could go through a published table of integrals (if such things still exist) and try to work them out, but the idea really seems alien to math. How about published collections of Math Olympiad and other competitions' problems?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [**Project Euler**](https://projecteuler.net)?  Mostly those problems are not solved by pure programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are such things for students —
specifically (typically) high-school (i.e., pre-collegiate) students. 
(I don’t know whether age limits are applied.) 
Perhaps the best known one is the International Mathematical Olympiad,
which is held annually ([home page](http://www.imo-official.org), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mathematical_Olympiad)). 
If you search for “math olympiad”, you’ll find others, mostly for even younger students
and/or for smaller competition areas (e.g., state or country).

Answer (score 0):

[Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org) is adding more college undergraduate-level math topics. It's not competitive in the same way that TopCoder or Project Euler are in the programming world, but it certainly is gamified like StackExchange is (points and badges). For the type of math that is taught to engineers, it's not hard to get a computer to evaluate answers. Evaluating proofs is another story.